# An example of using a reference to an abstract type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop

The following example from the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) shows that it is possible to make a reference to an abstract data type. Since we can't actually make an instance from an abstract class, I'm wondering why we would we want to make a reference. Can someone demonstrate an example?

```
abstract class Department {

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    printName(): void {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    }

    abstract printMeeting(): void; // must be implemented in derived classes
}

class AccountingDepartment extends Department {

    constructor() {
        super("Accounting and Auditing"); // constructors in derived classes must call super()
    }

    printMeeting(): void {
        console.log("The Accounting Department meets each Monday at 10am.");
    }

    generateReports(): void {
        console.log("Generating accounting reports...");
    }
}

let department: Department; // ok to create a reference to an abstract type
department = new Department(); // error: cannot create an instance of an abstract class
department = new AccountingDepartment(); // ok to create and assign a non-abstract subclass
```

Comment: Abstract class can be viewed as an interface with some methods that have an implementation. Why would we want to have a reference to that? For the same reason we would want to have a reference to an interface...

Answer (score 2):

As any other class, abstract class can be referred as interface:

```
let department: Department;
department = new AccountingDepartment();
department = new AnotherDepartment();
```

Since abstract class can serve as interface but it also exists at runtime, it is [commonly used as dependency injection token in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#class-interface).

Abstract class can be referred in case there's a need to refer parent class without instantiating it, e.g.:

```
if (someDepartment instanceof Department) ...
```